# Why/How image dataet dimensions get changed after it converts into tensorflow 2.0 dataset

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am using **CIFAR10** dataset.which has **original size: (60000,32,32,3)**
,after converting it into tensorflow dataset it gets converted into **tf.Tensor : shape(64,24,24,3)**.
What I understand from above is, per batch **there are 64 images of 24 x 24 in 3 channels**.(Lemme know if I am wrong)
Here's my code snippet.

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train)).batch(64).shuffle(10000)
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(lambda x,y:(tf.cast(x,tf.float32)/255.0,y))
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(lambda x,y:(tf.image.central_crop(x,0.75),y))
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(lambda x,y:(tf.image.random_flip_left_right(x),y))
train_dataset=train_dataset.repeat()
```

as per my understanding, it's because It's been centrally cropped by 75%. If it's right then how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. The `central_crop` crops the central region of the image by removing its outer parts. Therefore with `central_fraction=0.75`, the new dimensions of image would be `32*0.75 = 24`. Here's the documentation of the method:

````
central_crop(image, central_fraction)
    Crop the central region of the image(s).

    Remove the outer parts of an image but retain the central region of the image
    along each dimension. If we specify central_fraction = 0.5, this function
    returns the region marked with "X" in the below diagram.

         --------
        |        |
        |  XXXX  |
        |  XXXX  |
        |        |   where "X" is the central 50% of the image.
         --------

    This function works on either a single image (`image` is a 3-D Tensor), or a
    batch of images (`image` is a 4-D Tensor).

    Args:
      image: Either a 3-D float Tensor of shape [height, width, depth], or a 4-D
        Tensor of shape [batch_size, height, width, depth].
      central_fraction: float (0, 1], fraction of size to crop
    Usage Example: ```python >> import tensorflow as tf >> x =
      tf.random.normal(shape=(256, 256, 3)) >> tf.image.central_crop(x, 0.5) ```

    Raises:
      ValueError: if central_crop_fraction is not within (0, 1].

    Returns:
      3-D / 4-D float Tensor, as per the input.
````